# Type 'string' has no properties in common with type yourTableWhereUniqueInput'

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs

I'm currently developing a nestJS graphql API but I'm having some issues converting my graphql types to typescript classes.

My prisma schema has one single model inside of if

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model products {
  id          Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String?
  description String?
  price       Int?
  created_at  DateTime? @db.Date
  updated_at  DateTime? @db.Date
}
```

I convert this model to a graphQL type

```
type Product {
  id:ID!
  name:String!
  description:String!
  price: Int!
  category_id: Int
  created_at: Date!
  updated_at: Date!
}
```

With an update input

```
input UpdateProductInput {
  id:ID!
  name:String!
  description:String!
  price: Int!
  category_id: Int
  created_at: Date!
  updated_at: Date!
}
```

mutation and query are defined, I'll leave them out to reduce boilerplate.

Following the official docs for prisma and nextJS I convert my graphQL type to typescript classes using the generate-typings file

```
import { GraphQLDefinitionsFactory } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { join } from 'path';

const definitionsFactory = new GraphQLDefinitionsFactory();
definitionsFactory.generate({
  typePaths: ['./src/**/*.graphql'],
  path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/graphql.ts'),
  outputAs: 'class',
  customScalarTypeMapping: {
    DateTime: 'Date',
  },
  emitTypenameField: true,
});
```

This creates a file with all of the graphQL inputs and types converted to typescript classes, my productUpdateInput looks like this.

```
export class UpdateProductInput {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    price: number;
    category_id?: Nullable<number>;
    created_at: Date;
    updated_at: Date;
}
```

Then in my `products.service.ts` file I have the update method

```
  async update(
    id: Prisma.productsWhereUniqueInput,
    updateProductInput: Prisma.productsUpdateInput,
  ): Promise<products> {
    return this.prisma.products.update({
      where: id,
      data: updateProductInput,
    });
  }
```

Which in turn is called inside of my `products.resolver.ts` file

```
  @Mutation('updateProduct')
  update(@Args('updateProductInput') updateProductInput: UpdateProductInput) {
    return this.productService.update(
      updateProductInput.id, <= Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'productsWhereUniqueInput'.ts(2559)
      updateProductInput,
    );
  }
```

Which is where the error happens `Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'productsWhereUniqueInput'.ts(2559)`, Which maybe makes sense since the graphql to typescript converter has converted my id's to strings? but I'm not sure how to fix this cause if I change it to Int it breaks data input.

Comment: Use `as Prisma.productsWhereUniqueInput` in this line where type error appears

Comment: What does the type `Prisma.productsWhereUniqueInput` looks like ?

Comment: "but I'm not sure how to fix this cause if I change it to Int it breaks data input." Why does it break data input ?